# Erro em tempo de Execução 438: O Objeto não aceita propriedade ou Métodos

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Estou adaptando código VBA para raspagem, mas estou recebendo essa mensagem quando chega a etapa de enviar o dado para o formulário de Login.

> Erro em tempo de Execução 438: O Objeto não aceita propriedade ou Métodos

```
Public Sub VBA_extrair()
     Dim wb              As Workbook:        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     Dim wsParam         As Worksheet:       Set wsParam = wb.Worksheets("Param")
     Dim IE              As Object:          Set IE = New InternetExplorer.Application
     Dim stUsuario       As String:          stUsuario = wsParam.Range("A2")
     Dim stSenha         As String:          stSenha = wsParam.Range("B2")
     With IE
          .Visible = True
          .navigate "https://www.canalcliente.com.br/portal/canal_cliente/index.htm"
          While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: Wend
               With .document
                    .getElementById("txtUsuario").Value = username
                    .getElementById("txtSenha").Value = password
                    .getElementById("btnEntrar").Click
               End With
          While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: Wend
     End With
     Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: O erro acontece exatamente em qual linha?

Comment: OK! Eu aprendo rápido.

Comment: O erro aparecia a partir da .getElementById("txtUsuario").Value = username, mas a solução do Augusto Vasques resolveu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na página que você deseja acessar existe um iframe com o id "iframe1"

[image: iframe]

No seu código onde esta acessando o objeto "Document" deve considerar que existe um iframe, os elementos para login estão no iframe.

Vai precisar acessar o document principal > acessar o iframe > acessar o document do iframe, desta forma:

```
With .Document.frames.Item("iframe1").Document
```

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou.